# If else targetting a class in SASS

Tags: html, css, razor, sass

so I have this bit of code in razor:

```
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.HeroVideoLink))
                        {
                            <video preload="muted" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" playsinline class="@(Model.DisableVideoFitCover ? "no-display-cover" : "")">
                                <source src="@Url.ContentUrl(Model.HeroVideoLink)" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <video preload muted autoplay loop playsinline class="@(Model.DisableVideoFitCover ? "no-display-cover" : "")">
                                <source src="@Url.ContentUrl(Model.HeroVideo)" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        }
```

If the DisableVideoFitCover variable is true then the video tag is supposed to have a class called "no-display-cover". If not, it should be nameless.

I tried to apply styling with SASS:

```
    video,
        picture {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
    
          img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
    
            @if $no-display-cover {
              object-fit: none;
            } @else {
              object-fit: cover;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
            font-family: "object-fit: cover;";
          }
        }
    
        picture {
          z-index: 0;
        }
    
        video {
          z-index: 1;
          @if $no-display-cover {
            object-fit: none;
          } @else {
            object-fit: cover;
          }
          pointer-events: none;
        }
      }
```

Logic is supposed to be pretty simple - if the tag has class called "no-display-cover", then it should apply property:

> object-fit: none;

If not, then it should have a property:

> object-fit: cover;

Unfortunately it does not work and I am left without styling. Is my SASS if statement wrong, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

It had been a long time since i last use sass, but if i recall correctly, you can't use if/else like that without mixin, and since i'm not really good with mixin i'll fix it the beginner way.

```
video, picture {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        pointer-events: none;
        font-family: "object-fit: cover;";
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    &.no-display-cover {
        img {
            object-fit: none;
        }
    }
}

picture {
    z-index: 0;
}
    
video {
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    object-fit: cover;
    
    &.no-display-cover {
        object-fit: none;
    }
}
```